# Sarcastic response

Tags: idiomatic-language, sarcasm, responses

**Context**: Someone has behaved in a very bad way at work and wants to apologize for it a few days later. He's talking to a coworker of his.

**Person**: *I hope you can forgive me. I bought some chocolates to show everybody that I'm sorry...*

**Coworker**: (Sarcastic) *I'm sure that'll do it.*

**Question**: Does the response work to show sarcasm? Is it natural? Or do you have a better one?

Comment: Sarcasm doesn't work well in written dialogue: there is no intonation or body language

Comment: If this dialogue is intended to be spoken (such as in a dramatic scene), then the sarcasm can be expressed with intonation and the utterance "I'm sure that'll do it" would be enough. If this is not going to be spoken, then "I'm sure that'll do it" would not convey what you intended.